# Upload videos from ReactJS directly to Azure MediaService

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-media-services

I would like to upload videos directly from ReactJS component to Azure media service without middle server.

I investigated and found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/configure-connect-nodejs-howto) and this [@azure/arm-mediaservices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/arm-mediaservices) SDK. and it seems that secret tokens are involved and I assume it's not a good idea to use in on the client side.

Can someone share thoughts and examples how to simple upload a video directly from client side (ReactJS Component) to azure media service with a temporary token ?

I found a way to [upload Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob) to Blob in the way i want to, but I didn't find a way to do the same for videos to media services (without middle server side operations).

Comment: DId you ever figure this out?
I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that we do not recommend ever storing your account secrets on the client side.  You will still want a mid tier for that.  One simple way to do that securely is with Azure Functions.

All you need to do is creat the Asset and then get a SAS Url to the container to upload content into it.  Once you have those that there should be some samples out there if uploading to a SAS Url in Azure storage.